# Ruby split by whitespace

Tags: ruby, split, whitespace

How can I write a Ruby function that splits the input by any kind of whitespace, and remove all the whitespace from the result? For example, if the input is

```
 aa bbb
cc    dd ee
```

Then return an array `["aa", "bbb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following should work for the example you gave:

```
str.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').strip.split(" ")
```

it returns:

```
["aa", "bbb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
```

Meaning of code:

`/\s+/m` is the more complicated part. `\s` means white space, so `\s+` means one ore more white space letters. In the `/m` part, `m` is called a modifier, in this case it means, *multiline*, meaning visit many lines, not just one which is the default behavior.
So, `/\s+/m` means, find sequences of one or more white spaces.

`gsub` means replace all.

`strip` is the equivalent of `trim` in other languages, and removes spaces from the front and end of the string.

As, I was writing the explanation, it could be the case where you do end up with and end-line character at the end or the beginning of the string.

**To be safe**

The code could be written as:

```
str.gsub(/\s+/m, ' ').gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/m, '').split(" ")
```

So if you had:

```
str = "\n     aa bbb\n    cc    dd ee\n\n"
```

Then you'd get:

```
["aa", "bbb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
```

Meaning of new code:

`^\s+` a sequence of white spaces at the beginning of the string

`\s+$` a sequence of white spaces at the end of the string

So `gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/m, '')` means remove any sequence of white space at the beginning of the string and at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Candide! Would you (or anyone) mind giving a brief explanation of your code?

Comment: Rubocop fails your split (" ") because of the double quotes.

Comment: I love `ruby` .  Why can't it have scientific libraries so i'm allowed to actually use it..

Answer (score 69):

This is the default behavior of [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-split):

```
input = <<-TEXT
 aa bbb
cc    dd ee
TEXT

input.split
```

Result:

```
["aa", "bbb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
```

This works in all versions of Ruby that I tested, including 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, and 2.1.2.

Comment: This should be best answer for all latest ruby versions. At the time this question was asked (2012) I don't think it was possible to do it this way, which explains the "complex answers".

Comment: @Shashank Well, as I mentioned in the answer I tested this with Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0, and 2.1.2, and they all worked exactly as shown here. 1.8.7 was out all the way back in 2008, so even back when this answer was asked there was no reason the OP couldn't have just used `String#split`. No idea why nobody mentioned that until now...

Comment: This still works in 2.7.3 and is a lifesaver of a default behavior.

Answer (score 24):

```
input = <<X
     aa bbb
cc    dd ee
X

input.strip.split(/\s+/)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
input.split("\s")
```

If `"\s"` is used instead of `/\s/`, whites-paces will be removed from the result.

Answer (score 7):

As a slight modification to Vidaica's answer, in Ruby 2.1.1 it looks like

```
input.split(" ")
```

Will compensate for all whitespace, be it spaces, tabs, or newlines, yielding:

```
["aa", "bbb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
```