# Ruby regex to match a four item line

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using pdf-reader to read my monthly financial records.  All the lines I'm interested in start with the description, then the date ##/##/#### then two dollar amounts $#.## $#.## .

Like this:

```
Gas Station            12/12/2012         $68.00             $485.00
```

Sometimes the numbers will have brackets $(4.50) for returns or negative amounts.  I want all lines that conform to this "pattern" to be returned as a 4 item list per line.  So I'm matching the WHOLE LINE with undetermined amount of spaces and occasionally brackets on the prices.

```
require 'pdf-reader'
reader = PDF.Reader.new("month.pdf")
reader.pages.each do |page|
  page.split("\n").each do |line|
  if line # MATCHING REGEX HERE
     #HANDLE 4 VALUES FROM REGEX
  end
end
```

---

For anyone who wants to see how I've used the code here's the source https://github.com/danielpclark/INGdirect_pdf_processor .  Feel free to use it in your own projects for processing bank data.

Comment: Have you tried any regexs yet?  What worked? What didn't?

Comment: Why are you even using a regex?  Why not split the line on white space if everything is in columns?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537920/ruby-split-by-whitespace

Comment: `(.*)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*(\(?\$.\d+\.\d+\)?)\s+(\(?\$.\d+\.\d+\)?)` This worked for me.  The PDF's have a lot of other garbage data, like a bank image, lots of info, and some other sorted data.  So white space splitting won't work for me.

Comment: I plugged the pattern from @Andrea Singh and used the scan suggestion from @the Tin Man
`pattern=Regexp.new('(.*)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*(\(?\$.\d+\.\d+\)?)\s+(\(?\$.\d+\.\d+\)?)')`
`line.scan(pattern)` This gave me my desired output in a usable list/array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) is a good way to go after data like this:

```
string = 'This is some text
Gas Station   12/12/2012 $68.00   $485.00
This some more text
Reimbursement 01/01/2012 $(68.00) $(485.00)
'

string.scan(%r{^(.+?) \s+ (\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}) \s+ ([$()\d.]+) \s+ ([$()\d.]+) }x)
[
    [0] [
        [0] "Gas Station",
        [1] "12/12/2012",
        [2] "$68.00",
        [3] "$485.00"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "Reimbursement",
        [1] "01/01/2012",
        [2] "$(68.00)",
        [3] "$(485.00)"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
(.*)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*(\(?\$\d+\.\d+\)?)\s+(\(?\$\d+\.\d+\)?)
```

It will have 4 matches:

- description
- date
- first amount
- second amount

Here it is in Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/2mcrGZiAOe

You can also use named matches, since they are a bit more elegant (also the `x` modifier for multi-line regex):

```
if line_match = line.match(/
    (?<description>.*)\s+
    (?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*
    (?<amount_1>\(\$\d+\.\d+\)|\$\d+\.\d+)\s+
    (?<amount_2>\(\$\d+\.\d+\)|\$\d+\.\d+)/x)
  # now you can use: line_match[:date], line_match[:amount_1], etc.
```

Comment: Note: this matches the parens around the amounts before the $, not after it.  And this doesn't enforce matching parens if that matters to the OP.

Comment: Yes, they are optional, though because of the question mark following them: `\(?` and `\)?`

Comment: Two small tweaks and your regex will handle the format $(xx.xx) and even enforce matching parens: `(.*)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*(\$\(\d+\.\d+\)|\$\d+\.\d+)\s+(\$\(\d+\.\d+\)|\$\d+\.\d+)`

Comment: This did the trick.  I had to add a period after each dollar sign and then everything worked. `(.*)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*(\(?\$.\d+\.\d+\)?)\s+(\(?\$.\d+\.\d+\)?)` The periods after the dollar signs allowed for all brackets.